# Pytorch Lightning: Simulate a larger Batch Size for the Loss Function

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm running a training module using a loss function that is very dependent on having a large batch size. But, my batch size is currently limited by what I am able to fit on my GPU. Is there any way I can simulate a larger batch size by combining the results of several batches, then feeding it into the loss function?

I've tried combining the results of every 4 batches in training_step(), and returning the loss, but the I don't know what to return on the iterations where no loss is calculated.

I've also tried setting accumulate_grad_batches, but that only sums the individual gradients of each batch.

Comment: Hi! I guess you saw this: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/training_tricks.html#accumulate-gradients  Is your computation distributed?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, too. https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/discussions/12166#discussioncomment-3743508